# Как пользоваться Google Переводчик из кода C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-translate

Пытаюсь вот таким образом получить перевод:

```
 string url = String.Format("https://translate.google.ru/#{0}/{1}", languagePair, input);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

К примеру, ссылка генерируется вот такая:

> https://translate.google.ru/#en/ru/cat

но в `result` я ничего не нахожу... Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>

/// Translate Text using Google Translate API’s

/// Google URL – http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}

/// </summary>

/// <param name=”input”>Input string</param>

/// <param name=”languagePair”>2 letter Language Pair, delimited by “|”.

/// E.g. “ar|en” language pair means to translate from Arabic to English</param>

/// <returns>Translated to String</returns>

public string TranslateText(

    string input,

    string languagePair)

{


    string url = String.Format(“http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}”, input, languagePair);

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;


    string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);

    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(“id=result_box”) + 22, result.IndexOf(“id=result_box”) + 500);

    result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf(“</div”));


    return result;

}
```

[Using Google Translate API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shahpiyush/2007/06/09/translate-your-text-using-google-apis/)

Comment: А ты проверял этот код? У меня не получилось из него перевод получить...